# No cargan anuncios de prueba Admob

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un problema, hace un tiempo empece a probar los los anuncios de prueba de Rewarded con Admob, todo fue bien! Ahora que quise volver  probar los con anuncios de prueba no me salen, incluso cree un nuevo proyecto e implemente solo el Rewarded y no sale, pero si coloco un Interstitial aparece.

Siempre sale: onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad

Este es el codigo con el nuevo proyecto que hice:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
                reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Reward the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Tambien agregué:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Y luego

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Y en el logcat obtengo esto:

```
    06-08 19:17:06.525 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    This request is sent from a test device.
06-08 19:17:06.525 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
06-08 19:17:06.545 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    This request is sent from a test device.
06-08 19:17:06.585 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
06-08 19:17:16.985 2691-2714/android.cinemovil.xploit W/Ads: Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.DummyAdapter
    android.os.RemoteException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbo(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxm.zzbm(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzago.zzca(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahx.zzdn(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajy.run(Unknown Source)
```

Aclaro que solo estoy usando el emulador de Android Studio. Hace un par de semanas hice todo igual y me salieron los videos de recompensas de prueba sin problema.

No se a que se deba... Llegue a pensar si es que están fallando los Rewards de prueba de google, si alguien puede probar a ver si les funcionan, porque a mi no me va.

Answer (score 0):

Es bueno agregues siempre el mensaje mostrado en el LogCat para determinar el problema, en este caso el error se define como:

> Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

Puedes revisar que el error es:

> [ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) : La solicitud de anuncio fue exitosa, pero
>   no se devolvió ningún anuncio debido a la falta de inventario de
>   anuncios.

**Revisa que tu App Id en realidad tenga anuncios configurados.**

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y atención, sin embargo los Interstitial  si funcionan sin problemas, tanto con los ID de prueba de google y los mios propios de Admob, pero los Rewarded de prueba ni los míos logran cargar. ¿Donde configuro  `Revisa que tu App Id en realidad tenga anuncios configurados.` Pase todo el dia de ayer y madrugada igual y no hallo la solución :'(. Antes lo hice y me cargaron pero luego los deshabilite, ahora que los vuelo a habilitar no funcionan.

Comment: espera estas realizando la prueba pero no has revisado tu LogCat, se despliega un "TestDevice" para definirlo en el método .addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") esto agregarlo dentro de tu método loadRewardedVideoAd(), revisa el LogCat y comenta.

Comment: agregué `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)`

Y esto sale: `06-08 19:17:06.525 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    This request is sent from a test device.
06-08 19:17:06.525 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
06-08 19:17:06.545 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    This request is sent from a test device.
06-08 19:17:06.585 2691-2691/android.cinemovil.xploit W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings`

Comment: Ok si solo es una prueba puedes solo definir :;          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build(); de causalidad no cambiaste el paquete de tu aplicación si es una nueva debes manter el mismo paquete para el cual creaste el banner_ad_unit_id si cambia el paquete esto también provoca que no se muestren los anuncios!. Revisa este ejemplo para que veas lo que comento : https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_AdMob

Comment: El banner lo quite, en un proyecto que hice de prueba me funciona perfectamente los Interstitial  pero el Reward no. Recien volvi a crear el proyecto desde 0, implemente el reward y nada... Estoy usando los ID de anuncios de prueba, por lo menos debería de mostrarse, se que para los ID propios hay que esperar hasta que empiecen a dar anuncios.  ¿Puedes probar tu si los Reward te cargan? Estoy que instalo android studio en otro PC a ver.. jajajaja ya no hayo que hacer.

Comment: Importe el mismo proyecto de https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob/RewardedVideoExample y me sigue saliendo el error... Ya no es error de codigo, instale el android studio en otro ordenador y tambien salio el mismo error, ¿Dejaron de funcionar los Rewarded?